# Aligning two latex tables together

Tags: tables, minipage

new to latex here. I am trying to align two tables at the same level next to each other, but adding more columns in the second table pushed it below the first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c c c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Supervised} \\
\hline
XGBoost & LR & RF \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
0.76 & 0.45 & 0.83  \\  [0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c c c c c c c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Unsupervised} \\
\hline
LOF & ABOD & KNN & OCSVM & CBLOF & PCA & IF \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
0.11 & 0.07 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\  [0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to align/center them both together without changing the margin?

Comment: Why are you enclosing each tabular in a one-inch-wide minipage?

Comment: I actually have no idea what it does, I edited my columns based on existing templates

Comment: It's very likely a bad idea with unwanted side-effects. Remove the `minipage` environments and see how it goes.

Comment: also if you want someone to debug your code it helps to provide it in  form that my be used, so  complete document. But remove the `minipage` (as presumably your tables are wider than `1in` you must get warnings about them,then use  `\begin{tabular}[t]` so the tables align on their top row.

Comment: I have edited the code to complete it for reuse. Removing `minipage ` and adding `\begin{tabular}[t]` did not make any difference.

Comment: also of course you need to remove the paragraph break (blank line) if you want them in the same paragraph

Comment: Removing the breaks make the tables overlap each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}|c c c|@{}} 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{@{}|c|@{}}{Supervised} \\
\hline
XGBoost & LR & RF \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
0.76 & 0.45 & 0.83  \\  [0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}~%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}|c c c c c c c|@{}} 
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{}|c|@{}}{Unsupervised} \\
\hline
LOF & ABOD & KNN & OCSVM & CBLOF & PCA & IF \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
0.11 & 0.07 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\  [0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked out! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) visual? That's what the following code does. Additionally, like David's answer, you can just paste the two tables side-by-side by removing the blank line between them, or put everything in a single table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}% To make the tables fit within the text block (50% or original value)
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Supervised} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}
    XGBoost & LR & RF \\
    \midrule
    0.76 & 0.45 & 0.83 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tabular}{ *{7}{c} } 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{ c }{Unsupervised} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-7}
    LOF & ABOD & KNN & OCSVM & CBLOF & PCA & IF \\
    \midrule
    0.11 & 0.07 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}% To make the tables fit within the text block (50% or original value)
  \begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{ c }{Supervised}
      & \multicolumn{7}{ c }{Unsupervised} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-10}
    XGBoost & LR & RF
      &  LOF & ABOD & KNN & OCSVM & CBLOF & PCA & IF \\
    \midrule
    0.76 & 0.45 & 0.83
      & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Does seem way better to look at if both tables were combined.